# How to make Xcode's Storyboard assistant editor default to .m implementation file

Tags: xcode, storyboard

When using the assistant editor in Storyboard, the default behaviour is to open the .h file of the corresponding view controller.  But I rarely need to edit the .h file, instead I have to switch it to the .m file.

How can this be setup to automatically display the .m file every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **Xcode 5** the Assistant Editor now opens the .m file (rather than the .h file) by default.  If you click the horizontal arrows in the top-right you can jump between the .h and .m files.

Comment: Command-Control-[Up Arrow] toggles .h/.m. So does three finger swipe up on your trackpad, if you have Spaces and Mission Control set to use only four fingers.

Comment: Is there any way to change the default back to .h? In my case that is what I am always wanting to do.